# R: paste() won't concatenate but only repeats the original vector instead

Tags: r, vector

I was reading the book "Text Analysis with R for Students of Literature" and trying to reproduce the example. Therefore I have a vector in which every element is one line of text from a book and I am now attempting to merge these into a vector of the length one with the past() function. I have tried to play around with the arguments and read about it but no matter what, the resulting vector keeps the original length. I am using R studio 0.99.484 with R 3.2.3 on a linuxMint 17.2, in case that makes a difference.

This is my reproducible example

```
    > a <- rep("blabla", 5)
    > b <- paste(a, colapse= "X")
    > b
    [1] "blabla X" "blabla X" "blabla X" "blabla X" "blabla X"
    > length(b)
    [1] 5
```

The way I understand the documentation, I would expect the results be more like "blablaXbla... and the length have a value of 1.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes; the question is clear and reproducible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo on your code, it should be `collapse`.

```
a <- rep("blabla", 5)
b <- paste(a, collapse= "X")
b
```

which will output

```
[1] "blablaXblablaXblablaXblablaXblabla"
```

Comment: thank you so much. I find it quite tricky though that this typo doesn't produce an error.

Comment: @Bernd Konfuzius The reason that an error is not generated is the `...` argument in `paste` ("one or more R objects"). Your misspelled `collapse` is just treated as variable name of one of the object to be pasted. Try e.g. `paste(x = c("a", "b"), sepp = "c", colapse = "d", sep = ".", collapse = "_")`. See also [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html): "_Using `...` comes at a price — any misspelled arguments will not raise an error, and any arguments after `...` must be fully named. This makes it easy for typos to go unnoticed_"